How can I stream a video that I have stored in firebase storage in Android Kotlin
I am creating a time capsule kind of app, in which you can store text, images and videos and then that message will be displayed only on the specified time..the text and image messages are working fine..but while displaying video, Instead of the actual video it is showing it's url
Here is my code of adapter:
import android.net.Uri
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.timescape.Messages
import com.example.timescape.R
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MessageAdapter(private val messages: List<Messages>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private val TYPE_TEXT = 0
    private val TYPE_IMAGE = 1
    private val TYPE_VIDEO = 2

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val message = messages[position]
        return when {
            message.mediaUrls.isNotEmpty() && message.mediaUrls[0].endsWith(".mp4") -> TYPE_VIDEO
            message.mediaUrls.isNotEmpty() -> TYPE_IMAGE
            else -> TYPE_TEXT
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            TYPE_IMAGE -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_imgmsg, parent, false)
                ImageViewHolder(view)
            }
            TYPE_VIDEO -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_vidmsg, parent, false)
                VideoViewHolder(view)
            }
            else -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_textmsg, parent, false)
                TextViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val message = messages[position]
        val displayDateTime = Date(message.openDateTime)
        val currentDateTime = Date()

        if (currentDateTime.after(displayDateTime)) {
            when (holder) {
                is ImageViewHolder -> {
                    Picasso.get().load(message.mediaUrls[0]).into(holder.imageView)
                    holder.dateTimeView.text = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(message.storedDateTime))
                }
                is VideoViewHolder -> {
                    holder.bind(message.mediaUrls[0])
                    holder.dateTimeView.text = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(message.storedDateTime))
                }
                is TextViewHolder -> {
                    holder.textView.text = message.content
                    holder.dateTimeView.text = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(message.storedDateTime))
                }
            }
        } else {
            val futureMessageText = "This message will be displayed on ${SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(displayDateTime)}"
            when (holder) {
                is ImageViewHolder -> {
                    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_image_24)
                    holder.dateTimeView.text = futureMessageText
                }
                is VideoViewHolder -> {
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.baseline_videocam_24)
                    holder.dateTimeView.text = futureMessageText
                }
                is TextViewHolder -> {
                    holder.textView.text = futureMessageText
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = messages.size

    class ImageViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_image)
        val dateTimeView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_date_time)
    }

    class VideoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val playerView: PlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_view)
        val dateTimeView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_date_time)
        private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null

        fun bind(videoUrl: String) {
            if (exoPlayer == null) {
                exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(itemView.context).build()
                playerView.player = exoPlayer
            }

            val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(videoUrl))
            exoPlayer?.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            exoPlayer?.prepare()
            exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
        }

        fun releasePlayer() {
            exoPlayer?.release()
            exoPlayer = null
        }
    }

    class TextViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text)
        val dateTimeView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_date_time)
    }

    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        if (holder is VideoViewHolder) {
            holder.releasePlayer()
        }
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
    }
}


and here is my data class:
package com.example.timescape

data class Messages(
    val id: String="",
    val content: String="",
    val openDateTime: Long=0L,
    val mediaUrls: List<String> = listOf(),
    var isRead: Boolean = false,
    var type: String = "text",
    val storedDateTime: Long = 0L
)


Please help
Ive tried using video view and all stuff

You don't seem to be having a Layout XML for the Exoplayer, could you post your layout file?

Here it is <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
android:id="@+id/player_view"
android:layout_width="160dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
